# Error opening trace file android permission denied

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am getting a "error opening trace file: permission denied(13)" can somebody tell me what's that all about?

I've connected my phone instead of a virtual device...

And im kinda a noob in android still and I want to Log.d everything to see how it works
but it doesn't quite work on my phone.

Comment: i get no errors in code and the app is working as intended but i can't get the logs into my log cat

Comment: This is not caused by anything in your program, but by issues in Android itself.  There's not much you can do but ignore it.

Comment: that chmod 777 anr is not working for me it says operation not permitted

Comment: ok so i cant do nothing ? :(

Comment: how can i debug with messages then?

Comment: You will get the *meaningful* errors in logcat preceding this problem.    If your IDE is excessively filtering logcat and you can't turn that off, then use the command line version of the tool.  Also keep in mind that it may not be *your app* which is crashing and triggering this bug in the crash reporting code.  Unfortunately, factory apps and components crash relatively frequently.

Comment: ok i got that but all i want to know is how can i print something to my console or logcat? cause obviously my log.d doesnt really work

Comment: Show your code.  And run logcat from the command line... you will get an *absolute flood* of messages.  Unless your log attempts are invalid or being removed in the build process (proguard, etc) they will be in the unfiltered logcat.  Also there will be information about what was crashing to trigger the message in your title.

Answer (score -1):

You are likely writing the log to the App's reserved disk space. This space is reserved for that specific app only. (Unless you're rooted- but that's a different topic altogether)

You are probably trying to read the log file from outside of your app, which is not allowed because this disk space is protected.

I would suggest trying to write the file to a shared memory location.

Comment: No, this is a problem with Android itself, not the poster's program.